# Scroll Div to top of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a div to scroll to the top of the page when it begins to `slideDown()`. It's not doing what I intended, in fact I don't think it is doing anything at all.

Do I have the correct syntax to do a `slideDown()` and `scrollTop()` together?

```
jQuery('.pp-post-container').hide();
var prevPostID;      
jQuery('.pp-post-banner-overlay').on('click', function() {
  let postFullID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  let postNumID = postFullID.slice(23);
  jQuery('#pp-post-' + prevPostID).slideDown(1000);
  jQuery('#pp-post-container-' + prevPostID).slideUp(1000); 
  jQuery('#pp-post-' + postNumID).slideUp(1000);
  jQuery('#pp-post-container-' + postNumID).slideDown(1000).scrollTop();
  prevPostID = postNumID;
});
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (i.e. include your markup)?

Answer (score 3):

[`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop) without arguments will return the current vertical position.

If you want to scroll to top, you have to pass the value, that is 0 to the function.

`scrollTop(0)`

Read scrollTop with value in [jQuery documentaion](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop-value)